# Text on an Image button in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to add-in on my image button but somehow it's not working. How should I modify it?
Please advice. Thanks.

```
    <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px;" Text="Search" class="btn btn-info"
     style="background-image:url('/Content/Img/Image.png')" >
        onclick="Button1_Click1" Width="128px" Height="40px" />
```

[Search Btn Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMGz7.png)

Answer (score 1):

You've added two style attributes in your code. Try using only one.

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple style attributes will only apply the style mentioned in the last attribute. You can instead combine the two styles and apply them in a single attribute.

`CSS` styles can be separated by a `;`. Since you already have that on one style, you can just append the other style to it.

Apart from that, your code contains a `>` in the middle, which shouldn't be there. Fixed code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" style="margin-left:0px;background-image:url('/Content/Img/Image.png')" Text="Search" class="btn btn-info" onclick="Button1_Click1" Width="128px" Height="40px" />
```